# How to fetch URL in Cordova InAppBrowser system's web browser

Tags: cordova, webview, ionic2, inappbrowser

In my Ionic 2 app, I need to open an external url, using the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin, in the system web browser, then with target '_system'. Once opened I need to be able to read the url and then close the browser. If I use target '_blank', then with InAppBrowser, I can read the url and then close the web view, but with _system, that open that in the system's browser, I can't do this. Can anyone help me? Maybe even tell me if exists another plugin to do this. Thanks

edit: I tried both Cordova InAppBrowser https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html and Ionic Native InAppBrowser https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/ but it does not work

Comment: you can try window.open(url, '_self')

Comment: Unfortunately, for technical requirement, I have to use it only with system's browser and so with '_system'

Comment: You can't, when you use _system it will leave your app and open a different one (usually Chrome), and that app won't tell you anything, and also, your app is now closed. Why do you want to use _system instead of _blank?

Comment: I have to use _system to complete GoogleDrive authorization, according to recent specifications, which allow you to log on only through system browsers and not with web view in app. Anyway I solved with a workaround, doing a redirect to a jsp on my server and doing this stuff (read the url and close the browser) with an ajax script.